# Firebase ".indexOn" difficulty

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Tried to follow some previous answers, but the answers didn't work. 
My Data looks like:

```
"Test" : {
  "1d68e78d87bbdd5e9e4141b54765eac9" : {
    "Test" : "true",
    "num" : 0,
    "timestamp" : "2017-12-26T17:04:00.874Z"
  },
  "59e265ed2145425bd7660488120d69c6" : {
    "Test" : "true",
    "num" : 2,
    "timestamp" : "2017-12-26T17:29:32.807Z"
  },
  "aa7b4143099985cf2b2a7e31d91d6fb6" : {
    "Test" : "true",
    "num" : 1,
    "timestamp" : "2017-12-26T17:06:08.238Z"
  }
}
```

And I was trying to test both ordering first by 'num' or possibly 'timestamp' for my application. So my research lead me to these rules that they simply do not seem to work for me:

```
"rules":{
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true",
    "Test": {
        ".indexOn": ["num","timestamp"]
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the tests are still sorted by the hash. Going in deeper doesn't do anything either such as:

```
"rules":{
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true",
    "Test": {
        "$hash": {
            ".indexOn": ["num","timestamp"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you verifying the sorting? Where is the query you are performing? The data inside the Firebase console isn't going to reorder itself. indexOn just allows you to query faster on those sub values. Post the code for your query and the snapshot returned

Comment: @DoesData I believe you are right. I was testing it in REST by just doing a GET and I was assuming the data would be sorted by index. 
Tested with: 
Test.json?orderBy=\"num\"&limitToFirst=2 
And I was able to limit my data by index (which was what I wanted to test with firebase) Also doing the same call after removing "num" from .indexOn results in an error which is a roundabout way of verifying that data is indexed. Is using firebase-admin required/advised to test your data structure?

Comment: The Firebase Console *can* test your rules, however it *cannot* test your structure as there is really no requirements on a structure; they are a set of parent and child nodes and do not have to conform to any particular guideline.